# Using geometry nodes, I am trying to adjust speed of animation but also force its framerate to 12 fps afterwords, but one always disrupts the other

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

These blue nodes don't add up correctly. what would be the right way to speed up or slow down the animation (that's what the left multiply node is for) and still have the final result in 12 fps? (that's what the snap node does when on its own) my scene is set to 24. this is for animation purposes.

[image]

Comment: sorry, i don't really understand what you want to achieve. It should be pretty clear that if you change fps, the speed of the animation will change. So by changing fps afterwards, the animation speed will change. Or you render 2x, one for 12 fps and one for 24 fps and you adapt that with GN. Is this what you want?

Comment: The whole geometry node is a huge simulation of grass waving in the wind. I would like to adjust the speed of the wind and then force that to 12 fps

Comment: @Cimo ..it looks as if _all_ modification should be a function of `snap (seconds, 1/12)` .. so, put your time through that right at the beginning, and then do everything else as you normally would.

Comment: Strange. when I set the Snap nodes Increment value to 1/12 it sometimes skips 3, 2 and even 1 frame. I cant get it to 12 fps at all. I just noticed that when the increment value is 1 that it changes every 20 frames

Comment: @Cimo there will be a floating-point slip.. 'leap-frames' like leap-years,, depending on your render fps.  if you render at 24 fps, you could use the `Frames` input instead of `Seconds`, and skip every other frame. That would ensure sync.

Comment: You are right, using the scene time frame plugged into the Snap's value and setting the increments to 2 makes it 12 fps.
However I am still not sure how to plug the other multiply node into this to not offset the 12fps animation style. even the snapping node offsets it.

Comment: If _everything_ comes after the skip. you should be OK? Just treat the skip as your input time.

Comment: But if I slow it down after the skips, then the skips get stretched. what is the node hierarchy that works? how do I connect them properly?

Comment: Yea you were right in the end. Tame scene - frame plugged into Snap on 2 increments and then multiply node. Starting with numbers very close to 0 because it had HUGE leaps in speed. must have confused me. Thank you Robin!